# How do I get away with getting these garbage numbers

Tags: c++

Here, I'm trying to make a program that basically gets the input from the user (from 0~100) and multiply that input by 123456789 without using long, double and float. So, I made some for loops, but I ended up getting garbage numbers

'''

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;

int arr_1[9] = { 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 };
int arr_2[10];  //store n * arr_1[i] in here
int arrsize = sizeof(arr_1) / sizeof(arr_1[0]);

char arr_3[10];

if (n>=0 && n<=100) {                //assume that I typed 2 for n
    for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) { 
        arr_2[i] = n * arr_1[i];    //9*2 = 18, 8*2 = 16, etc..
        int number = arr_2[i] / 10; //number = 1
        if (number >= 1) {      //true
            arr_2[i] -= number*10;  //18-10 = 8
            arr_2[i + 1] += number; //arr_2[2] = 1
            std::cout << "arr_2[i+1] : " << arr_2[i+1] << std::endl;    //ended up getting garbage numbers...which leads to incorrect result

        }
        arr_3[i] = arr_2[i] + '0';  //'8'
```

'''

So I did some research, but I'm still unclear of why this is not working (maybe I'm getting confused with other language). Is there anyway I can get away with these garbage numbers?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question,  yet you don’t need to calculate `arrsize`. You know that the number of elements in `arr_1` is 9 because you wrote it that way. What you probably should do is lead off with `const int arrsize = 9;`. Then you can write `int arr_1[arrsiza];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with your long multiplication algorithm.

For one thing, if you look at what you're doing with carries, you're writing the carry to arr_2[i+1], and then the next time through the loop you're overwriting it with whatever you calculate.

(In fixing this, you're likely go to run into the problem that you haven't initialized `arr_2`, so it will likely be full of whatever happened to be in memory before your program started.)

For another, if n is large enough, you're going to run out of space in `arr_2` to hold the results.

If you fix these problems you should have a working program, but you should also reconsider things like naming variables `number` or `arr_3`, converting a sequence of digits to an array of four-byte ints holding ASCII characters, etc.  These aren't great software engineering practices.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it gets garbage numbers because you didn't initialized the arrays. You can think that you initialized with new numbers in for loop function, but program might produce garbage number if you don't initialize it when you make a new array. Try after initializing the arrays at first.